# Dynamic offset printing not working as expected in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, templates

I've got a worksheet that's a template containing 10,000 lines of formulas which simply pull available data from another sheet.  I'm trying to make it only print the displayed data, but by default it pulls all 10,000 lines. So I created an entry in the Name Manager called DynPrint with the following formula:

```
=OFFSET('Template Log'!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(IF('Template Log'!$B$9:$B$10000<>0,'Template Log'!$B$9:$B$10000)),22)
```

Then on the `Print_Area` entry I set it to `=DynPrint`.  Initially it works just like I expect it to and only displays the appropriate data to print.  But when I open the file and update the data set, the print area stays the same. Checking Name Manager reveals that the formula for Print_Area no longer says `=DynPrint` and instead shows a hard range.

What have I done wrong and how do I get it to dynamically print all the time like I need it to?

Comment: try: `=INDIRECT("DynPrint")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Scott, but when I did that it wanted to print all 102 pages.  I changed it back to =DynPrint and worked fine.  I think the issue is that the details of the Print_Area change once I update the dataset on the other tab or when I close the file and reopen.  Perhaps both.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this problem, how did you set the Print_Area?
These my steps:

*Define Name* first- set *Print_Area*- Change the named Range with formula- save.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lee. I went about it the same way. Page Layout>Print Area to initially get started. Then Name Manager>New to create the DynPrint. Then changed the details of Print_Area. Everything works perfect apparently until I close the file.  Then on reopening the details for Print_Area have reset.  Or maybe it's updating the dataset on the other tab.  Maybe it's both.

Comment: Go to C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART, delete all files and folders from it.(If it's necessary, try to back up it.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've got a small, very subtle, but very critical, difference between what you did and what `Lee` did.

Your post makes it sound like you are directly specifying the Named Range itself in the Page Setup dialog box. NOT what `Lee` is doing at all. So where it says `Print Area:` is where I believe you are placing the Named Range.

And that works, for a moment, as closing the dialog causes Excel to resolve that Named Range to the value it has at that moment. If you printed, then immediately opened the Page Setup dialog back up, you'd see the formal range specified, not the Named Range. So A1:K100, not "DynPrint". No need to save and close the spreadsheet, then re-open it for that to occur, it occurred the moment you closed the dialog before even printing.

(In fact, doing something much more like `Lee` is, and doing the save, close, re-open sequence does not lose anything on my machine. And logically, shouldn't, so all is right in the world.)

So, how to keep a viable dynamic print range? You CAN change to a Table, because Excel will retain a Table reference, at least when it's the whole Table. I have not tried a partial Table (did this in my own work some time back, not today). If, like me, you did not want to do that (in my case, because I wanted `SPILL` formulas to fill the area to print and those will not work inside Tables), you have to seek something else.

The problem you are seeing is that resolution to a true address being permanent the way you are doing it. Change to this, or `Lee`'s version, and that will be taken care of.

What `Lee` does is spot on, though it has an extra step that is not necessary. If you have lots of Named Ranges, lots of pages, and lots of Print Ranges, but never click to limit the Named Range dialog to just your current page, you could easily change the wrong page's Print Range if you do it directly, so perhaps `Lee`'s extra step is useful as a way to give the actual dynamic formula a distinct name on each page and not worry about that so much.

Create a print range any way you wish, so that one exists for the next step. Then you can place your dynamic formula directly in the Print Range's own `Refers to:` box. No need to place it in its own Named Range, then place that Named Range in the Print Range's box. But it works either way.

Doing that gives me a truly dynamic (add a number in column B and see the Print Range expand right there on the screen) print range. Doesn't matter that it resolves to a true address every time I go to print because every next time I engage it, the formula updates before it resolves yet again. So exactly what you are wanting.

Now, separate issue, and you have a separate question for it as the rules ask for, is making sure you have the right formula. I shall answer that part there.